# How AWS does GPU virtualization?

Tags: amazon-ec2, virtualization, cuda, graphics-processing-unit

What kind of technology is Amazon using for GPU virtualization ? Can multiple VMs on an AWS GPU instance concurrently share GPU and have acceleration for their CUDA/ openCL programs ? I know following are the methods possible for GPU Virtualization:

1) API remoting: VMs emulate the GPU and the GPU on the host is called in RPC fashion from the VMs. This could be shared-memory based or network based remoting.

2) Actual GPU virtualization where multiple VMs can concurrently share a GPU. But as far as I know, Xen (used by AWS) does not supports this.

I have to do a project where I need to share an organization's GPUs in an internal, private cloud. I need to know through what technology, GPGPU in Cloud is commercially provided by AWS ? I have searched thoroughly, and my conclusion is that no open source software is mature enough to do this commercially.

Please Help!

Comment: Amazon do not publicise there Server setup. If you have an requriment you would need to speak to there sales team who may be able to help.

Comment: The way they do it is (most likely) a trade secret shared between amazon and their vendor, and you're not going to be doing it their way.  However, there are ways of doing this in (for instance) ESXi 5.1, for certain use cases.

Answer (score 1):

NVidia's Tesla GPUs allow *a degree* of virtualisation, they have an API that you could look into but I'm far from an expert - they don't support this on any other of their cards though.

Comment: K20xs only I seem to recall. And even then, it's SR-IOV isn't it?